# Detecting a valid web address

Tags: ios, swift, urlcomponents

I am trying to write some code that lets me both validate that a string is in fact a **valid web address to reach a remote server** && be able to unwrap it safely into a url for usage.

From what gathered from various posts and Apple's source code:

```
URLComponents is a structure designed to parse URLs based on RFC 3986 and to construct URLs from their constituent parts.
```

and based on w3 schools:

```
A URL is a valid URL if at least one of the following conditions holds:

The URL is a valid URI reference [RFC3986]....
```

Would this code suffice to detect **addresses that reach remote servers on the world wide web?**

```swift
import Foundation

extension String {
    
    /// Returns `nil` if a valid web address cannot be initialized from self
    
    var url: URL?  {
        guard
            let urlComponents = URLComponents(string: self),
            let scheme = urlComponents.scheme,
            isWebServerUrl(scheme: scheme),
            let url = urlComponents.url
        else {
            return nil
        }
        return url
    }
    
    /// A web address normally starts with http:// or https:// (regular http protocol or secure http protocol).
    private func isWebServerUrl(scheme: String) -> Bool {
        (scheme == WebSchemes.http.rawValue || scheme == WebSchemes.https.rawValue)
    }
}
```

Can you provide some feedback on this approach and let me know if there are any optimizations that can be made? or if it's incorrect?

Any and all comments are appreciated.

Comment: What is your definition of a valid web address?  Is the following a valid web address according to your definition?  http://www.apple.coom/

Comment: A web address for a remote server. I re-worded the question :thumbs_up:

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could go even simpler and do

```swift
import Foundation

extension String {
    
    /// Returns `nil` if a valid web address cannot be initialized from self
    var url: URL?  {
        return URL(string: self)
    }
    
    /// A web address normally starts with http:// or https:// (regular http protocol or secure http protocol).
    var isWebURL: Bool {
        get {
            guard let url = self.url else { return false }
            return url.scheme == "http" || url.scheme == "https"
        }
    }
}
```

**Explanation**
Initializing a `URL` using a string will return `nil` if the string isn't a valid url, so you can get the url by just `init`ing a URL object. Additionally, checking the scheme is super easy because `URL` has a property `scheme` that we can check against the required parameters.

Comment: Wonderful - Your answer is a combination of the two best answer's i've received from similar but improperly posed posts I made earlier. Thanks a lot @thecoolwinter!

Comment: @AdamDahan Totally :) glad I could help!

Comment: @AdamDahan much easier just check if the URL is not a file URL [isFileURL](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nsurl/1408782-isfileurl)

Comment: @AdamDahan I already told you how you should approach this. Make a url request if it is not a file url and check the response